# Query wikidata for wikipedia urls in multiple langauges

Tags: sparql, wikipedia-api, linked-data, wikidata-api

I'm trying to use Wikidata as an intermediary to get from a unique identifier listed in Wikidata (for example VIAF ID) to a Wikipedia description.

I've managed to piece together this query to get the Wikipedia page ID from a given VIAF ID (`"153672966"` below is the VIAF ID for "Southern Illinois University Press"):

```
SELECT ?pageid WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P214 "153672966". 
    [ schema:about ?item ; schema:name ?name ;
      schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> ]
     SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org" .
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .
         ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .
    }
}
```

This results in the pageid `9393762` which I am able to lookup in the Wikipedia API and get the introduction text I need using this request:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&pageids=9393762
```

The resulting response includes an unparsed description (`explaintext`) taken from the first section in the wikipedia article, so this gets me where I need to be given the language is english.

Now the problem is that I need to use this on a internationalized site where I might not even know upfront which languages might be used in the future. The query against Wikidata is supposed to run as a batch job on the backend, while fetching the actual descriptions from Wikipedia will be done from the frontend and be rendered asynchronously.

Ideally I would want the Wikidata query to return a `pageid` for each given language where there is a Wikipedia article available. On the frontend I would then check whether the current active language has a `pageid` associated and call the Wikipedia api or render a fallback if no `pageid` is given.

In the future I would need to make similar queries with other library related identifiers such as ISNI for example, but I don't imagine that being much different than the current use-case.

Is this a reasonable way to get the job done and how can I expand it to support multiple languages?

Answer (score 2):

To get the explaintext you don't necessarily need the `pageid` but the page title is enough.

The page titles in all languages you get from Wikidata with the following query:

```
SELECT ?item ?title ?site WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P214 "153672966" .
      [ schema:about ?item ; schema:name ?title ;
      schema:isPartOf ?site ] . 
}
```

And afterwards you can use Wikipedia API to get the explaintext:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Southern Illinois University Press
```

The downside of working with page titles is that they are not stable. So you will need to run your batch job regularly to check for renamings of articles.

Comment: Right. I was considering trying to switch to titles as I was looking at the Wikipedia REST API and could not find pageid there, but I was not aware that I could get all the translated titles like that. Thanks for that! What is your opinion on using the REST API as opposed to the endpoint I'm using above?

Comment: And renaming was why I did not go with titles initially, but we will need to run it in a batch job anyway, so I think we can manage.